# Ubuntu won't normal boot as it "Failed to start User Manager for UID 121" after wine installation but boots fine with resume option in recovery mode

Tags: wine, boot-repair, nomodeset

Im running **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**, kernel **4.15.0-112-generic**.

I've never used wine before, so I was curious and gave it a try yesterday. It worked fine, however, ever since my ubuntu just won't boot telling me:

`[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.`

I aways have to enter the recovery mode and resume to normal boot.

How can I fix that?
Can I simply set the nomodeset option for normal boot?

[image: this is how it looks]

**EDIT:** After adding the nomodeset option my normal boot works just fine. Still, I'm pretty sure it didn't solve the actual problem... it's just hiding one of its symptoms.

**EDIT2**: I've removed the nomodeset option and everything works fine again. No idea why though.

Comment: excuse me can you explain how can you remove the nomodest ?

Comment: for me it is the file /etc/default/grub. In line 10 a changed "quiet splash nonmodeset" back to "quiet splash" (without nonmodeset).